# Mirror a TFS folder to a shared folder

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have a folder in TFS that I want to publish to a shared folder on my local network (read only access).  I would like that anytime a change (or new file) is checked in, the files will be automatically updated in the shared folder.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd set up an automated build, with the server workspace mapped to the folder you want to monitor. The only thing the build would need to do is call out to xcopy. You'll probably need to create a custom workflow to do this but that should be fairly easy (famous last words)

Comment: This would work and probably be the easiest way to handle this. The downside is you need to dedicate a machine for use as the build machine. I guess you can use a VM for that. Remember to setup the build as Continuous Integration (CI).

Comment: I was thinking of adding some plugin to the TFS server but that is of course not as easy as James's solution, though it does save you a build machine.

Comment: @Duat Le, whilst I would recommend using a dedicated build server. You can run the build agent on any machine, including a desktop.